# How to set Widget button visibility?

Tags: android, button, widget, set, onupdate

Hi first of all i'm sorry for my bad english. How to set RemoteViews .setViewVisibility? I want to hide widget button when i click on it. 
Here is my code. Thanks for help.

```
@Override
public void onUpdate(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager,
        int[] appWidgetIds) {

    final int N = appWidgetIds.length;
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++){

        int appId = appWidgetIds[i];
      widget = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.widget_wyglad);
      Intent Tv = new Intent(context, client_widget.class);
      Tv.setAction(AKCJA);
      Tv.putExtra("test", AKCJA);
      PendingIntent ptv = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, Tv, 0);
      widget.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.bt_wid_tv, ptv);
      appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(appId, widget);
    }

  super.onUpdate(context, appWidgetManager, appWidgetIds);
}

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

    Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();
    if (extras != null){

        widget.setViewVisibility(R.id.bt_wid_tv, View.GONE);

    }
    else {Log.d("ERR", "EXTRAS ELSE");}

    super.onReceive(context, intent);   

}

}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have done everything right about making the view hidden. just include this in your code-

In your onReceive method-

```
if (intent.getAction().equals(AKCJA)) {
widget.setViewVisibility(R.id.bt_wid_tv, View.GONE);
}
```

Comment: I try both solutions and nothing happend. 
Should i try update widget after:


       widget.setViewVisibility(R.id.bt_wid_tv, View.GONE)

Comment: yes..exactly..after changing the view always use this code- 
    appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(appId, widget);

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried using `INVISIBLE` instead of `GONE`? Gone will remove the view as if it were never there. And invisible will hold the view's place in the layout, but make it invisible.

```
rv.setViewVisibility(R.id.bt_wid_tv, View. INVISIBLE);
```

Answer (score -2):

Yeah it finally work,
There's what i change:

```
int appId = appWidgetIds[i];
```

change to:

```
appId = appWidgetIds[i];
```

next i add static int appId:

```
public class client_widget extends AppWidgetProvider {

static int appId;
```

finally add this new AppWidgetManager and update line:

```
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

AppWidgetManager newAppWidgetManager = AppWidgetManager.getInstance(context);

        if (intent.getAction().equals(AKCJA)) {
            AppWidgetManager nowy = AppWidgetManager.getInstance(context);

            widget.setViewVisibility(R.id.bt_wid_tv, View.GONE);

            newAppWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(appId, widget);
```

Thanks @Naddy